# How can I install MatLab R2015a in Ubuntu 12.04 (32- bit) system?

Tags: matlab

I have 1GB RAM, Pentium Dual Core Laptop(32-bit only). I want to install MatLab R2015a in my laptop. I have its software, Key and all necessary things.  My Operating System is Ubuntu 12.04. Can anyone tell that how can I install it(MatLab) manually.

Do I have to upgrade the software to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

Comment: AFAIK MATLAB R2015a is only available for 64-bit Linux - see the [Sysetm Requirements](http://www.mathworks.com/products/availability/index.html)

Comment: @steeldriver Can you write an answer for that? That link you gave now points to R2016b though, so you would want to link to http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2015a_Linux.pdf instead.

Answer (score 0):

Get Ubuntu updated and follow the instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

To Update Ubuntu open terminal and:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```